# Selenium: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

My Class name is different, below is the code:

```
package Udemy;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class InvokeChrome {

    public static void main(String[] args) 

    {
    System.getProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");   
    WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
    driver.get("https://google.com");


    }


}
```

**WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();**

> Error:  Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver
>
> driver.get("https://google.com"); Error:
>   driver.get("https://google.com");

P.S: the same works on my laptop, following same procedures

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you have added the external jars in the ModulePath.

Solution:

Remove the external jars from the node "Modulepath".
Select the node "Classpath" then add the external jars.
Review that all the jars are under the node "Classpath"

Answer (score 0):

Use setPropety instead of using getProperty.It will work.

```
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");   
 WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("https://google.com");
```

Comment: Thanks Dhruv.. Somehow I missed it..However the same issue is ocurring.
package Udemy;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class InvokeChrome {

 public static void main(String[] args) 
 
 {
 System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe"); 
 WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver();
 driver.get("https://google.com");
 
 
 }
 

}

Comment: post your error logs and did you add all libraries which required to run this code?

Comment: Yes, all libraries are added. 
error log:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver
 The method get(String) is undefined for the type WebDriver

 at Selenium/Udemy.InvokeChrome.main(InvokeChrome.java:12)

Comment: Which chromeDriver version you are using ? and as I found you missing any jar files to be added into your build path. Refer this link and verify once again you added all required jar files into your build path. https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/3691

Comment: Version 69.0.3497.100 (Official Build) (64-bit) The version on my laptop and PC is same, it works on laptop but fails on PC

Comment: Your laptop and PC configuration might be different, Both are 64 Bit? What is your ChromeDriver Version 32 Bit or 64 BIt? as i found this error only comes when you missing any jar files

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue and resolved it by adding the following jars to buildpath - selenium-java.jar, selenium-remote-driver.jar, selenium-support.jar

Answer (score 0):

Resolved this issue in Maven project by adding the following dependency in POM.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
```