# Install chromedriver in eclipse Java

Tags: java, selenium

I am trying to learn about selenium in Java and I have started this code with my first failure ..
Here's the code I have in eclipse for Java

```js
package selenium.basics;


import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class ChromeTest {

 public static void main(String[] args) {

  System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\selenium-java-3.141.59\\drivers\\chromedriver.exe");
  ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
  
  driver.get("http://www.google.com");
 }
 
}
```

and I got this error message

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver
    at selenium.basics.ChromeTest.main(ChromeTest.java:12)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    ... 1 more
```

Tried using this line but the same problem

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
```

I am confused a little about libraries path
[image]

I tried this ...
[image]

Then I changed this line

```
WebDriver driver = (WebDriver) new ChromeDriver();
```

And this is what I got now

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/chrome/ChromeDriver
at selenium.basics.ChromeTest.main(ChromeTest.java:11)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: 
org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:583)
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
... 1 more
```

I am still trying and I have copied and paste the chromedriver.exe to the same path of the project (I thought this may be a problem)
and here is the new code in snapshot. Notice the red line at new ChromeDriver part .. this may solve the problem if we get rid of this red line
[image]

Comment: Have you installed Selenium WebDriver? This is a nice tutorial for it: https://www.guru99.com/installing-selenium-webdriver.html

Comment: Yes I have installed the Selenium WebDriver .. and I almost did all what is there in the turorial.

Comment: @Fang I have added a snapshot. What should I select : Classpath or Modulepath?

Comment: It's hard to say what's wrong, but this problem seems to refer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589061/selenium-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-chromedriver-to-webdriver

Comment: @Fang I already did this `Remove the external jars from the node "Modulepath". Select the node "Classpath" then add the external jars. Review that all the jars are under the node "Classpath"` and I got rid of this red line ..
And I got new errors .. long message at console!! Starting with `Invalid port. Exiting...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several hours of frustrating and a lot of search, I could find out the problem for me
It was because of the regional settings for numbers (I am using Arabic format)

So I logged into Control Panel >> Region >> Format tab >> Format dropdown >> English (United States)

Then everything is OK now and the problem solved