# Error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver

Tags: selenium-chromedriver

I am using a new laptop (on my old laptop I have no issues with running selenium tests) and I keep getting error: Type mismatch: cannot convert from ChromeDriver to WebDriver. All the JARs files are added under the classpath. I do not know how to fix this error.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/29ItG.png)

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you have added the external jars in the ModulePath.

Solution:

Remove the external jars from the node "Modulepath". Select the node "Classpath" then add the external jars. Review that all the jars are under the node "Classpath"

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52589061/selenium-type-mismatch-cannot-convert-from-chromedriver-to-webdriver)

Comment: I do no have any external jars under the 'Modulepath' - all the external jars are under 'Claspath'.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to resolve this issue by doing the following:

a) when creating a new class I used default package (on 'create a new class' screen the project field is automatically populated - I cleared that filed and the class was created under default project.

[default project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPtI3.png)

b) I deleted the module-info.java that is showing within the src folder:

[module-info.java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sVR6T.png)